# Not a valid Win32 WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

[image: Not a valid Win32 WP7]

I don't know this problem

```
Error   1   Unable to copy file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Toolkit\Oct11\Bin\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll" to "Bin\Debug\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll". Not a valid Win32 FileTime.
Parameter name: fileTime    PanoramaApp1
```

My OS Win7 64bits, I try it on 32bits same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the .DLL through Windows Explorer, what does it say the Create, Modified and Accessed times are?

It may be possible that the value for one of these fields exceeds the FileTime type, have you tried reinstalling the SDK?

Comment: In Visual Studio go to the toolbar at the top and then navigate to the "Build" menu, from there you should see a "Clean Solution" option.

Comment: Ok I do it, and now tell me the ApplicationIcon.png is not Win32

Comment: Open the image in Paint, save the image (with no changes made, but editing it in paint modified the time stamps). Again use "Clean Solution" and try again.

Comment: Ok thanks now I know my mistakes, thanks a lot
file missing, just add it and modify it then clean and rebuild again :)

Comment: Good to know, feel free to upvote the answer/mark as accepted if it helped you - it will also let other users know it's a somewhat useful solution too!

Comment: ok, plz can you help me in other question,I asked Apr 4 at 13:28
title "Error RDP protocol WP7"
and thanks a lot

Comment: this is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012110/error-rdp-protocol-wp7